# Designing a food ingredient class in OOP

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I want to suggest recipes to my users, so I'm fetching recipes from a `JSON` source (including their ingredients).

At the moment, ingredients can be fetched from three ways:

1. `3 tomatoes` (no particular unit)
2. `125ml of milk` (volume unit, either metric or imperial)
3. `500g of pasta` (mass unit, either metric or imperial)

### Requirements

I want to use a DDD approach, so a layered architecture.

I need to be able to display the ingredient as-is, like suggested in my bullet list above. The user can choose between a metric or imperial view.

1. `3 tomatoes`
2. `125ml of milk` or `1/2 cup of milk`
3. `55g of pasta` or `2 ounces of pasta`

#### My challenge

I'm not sure how to design the class in order to respect encapsulation and to ensure an *easy-to-maintain* design.

My first idea was to represent units with a `Unit` class, so my `Ingredient` class would hold a quantity and a unit. But in some cases, the ingredient is unitless. With this idea in mind, my `IngredientPresenter` would look like this:

```
public String present(Ingredient ingredient) {
    if ( ingredient.isUnitless() ) 
        return ingredient.getQuantity() + " " + ingredient.getName();
    else
        return ingredient.getUnit() + " " + ingredient.getName();
}
```

I'm not convinced with this approach since I could have many different types of `units`, and so my `IngredientPresenter` would grow rapidly (and violating [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)).

Then, I thought I could go with *polymorphism*. While it seems a good approach, I don't know what to expose in my interface since my implementations would be completely different. I would need to expose my methods in implementations, so loosing all the benefits of *polymorphism*. My `IngredientPresenter` would look like below:

```
public String present(Ingredient ingredient) {
    if ( ingredient instanceof UnitlessIngredient ) {
        UnitlessIngredient actualIngredient = (UnitlessIngredient) ingredient;
        return actualIngredient.getQuantity() + " " + actualIngredient.getName();
    } else {
        WithUnitIngredient actualIngredient = (WithUnitIngredient) ingredient;
        return actualIngredient.getUnit() + " " + actualIngredient.getName();
    }
}
```

Actually, I think my problem is that I don't know how to represent *units* properly, so I'm looking your help.

Thank you for your time!

### Edit

I will not *only* present my ingredient. In my domain layer, I need to calculate the ingredient's nutriment facts. So, depending on its quantity (or volume, or mass), the calculation is done differently. One simply multiply the nutriment facts by the quantity while the other must perform a *pro-rata*. That's a perfect case of polymorphism.

Comment: DDD architecture doesn't exist. And it seems you're trying to overengineer the solution. Keep it simple

Comment: Look at the [quantity](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html) pattern. For your unitless ingredient, just use a unit of "piece".

Answer (score 2):

Definitely go with polymorphism.

The way this is normally done is that `present()` stops being a standalone function in a vacuum, and it becomes a method of the `Ingredient` instead.

So, you essentially call the `Ingredient` to render itself into a string.  Possibly with some parameter indicating metric vs. imperial, which the ingredient may have some use for, or it may ignore if unitless.  Simple, elegant, tried, it works.

Comment: That would be a great idea, but it does not allow me to present my ingredient in different ways. Let's say I have an _abbreviated_ presentation and a _full-text_ presentation. Moreover, my `Ingredient` class (in domain layer) is aware of its presentation (which is in a higher level).

Comment: First part: no problem at all: add an "abbreviated" flag to `present()`, or split it in two methods: `presentAbbreviated()` and `presentFullText()`.  Second part: ("Moreover, ...") I did not understand that.

Comment: Going that way, we violate the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), or in other words, we need to add methods in order to add functionalities. I also have the problem I need to _persist_ my ingredients, so I will have a method that convert my class to a persistence's `DTO`. Again, I want to change my persistence, it means I need to add a new method :). In a DDD approach, your domain layer should not know about (or be aware of) other layers.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Well, if you really want to be so picky with design principles, then yes, this answer is not suitable.  On the other hand, you could opt for relaxing design purity in favour of productivity, in other words, consider this approach as a pragmatic compromise. (So, screw the open/closed principle, polymorphic presentation *gets things done*.)

Comment: In a more complex project, and in classes closer to the core of the design, I would strive for purity; but in the scenario you are describing, it is probably not worth it.  Unless this is an exercise with the precise aim of finding how to get things done in an as pure as possible way; in which case, let's hope there will be more answers.

Comment: Also, I should add that for every lofty principle there is a lofty counter-principle.  So, I will see your Open/Closed principle and I will raise you a [Tell, Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle.